# Fotorama 4 API?

Tags: jquery, plugins, gallery, slideshow, fotorama

I've started using [Fotoramajs 4](http://fotorama.io/). I had some experience with this plugin's previous versions, but I guess API of the forth version is different. There are some really useful examples with data attributes, but there are not enough of them. For example I need to change thumbnails border width and color, but I may only set the height of thumbnails with "data-thumb-height". I'm not an advanced developer to check the original code and figure it out myself. So far I've solved my needed with CSS, but I think it's not the correct way of doing things. How can I find api according to only the source code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

API docs is on the way. See this comment for the details: https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/17#issuecomment-20994875

Answer (score 1):

Official Fotorama 4 API has arrived: http://fotorama.io/customize/api/